# Can't return word document, generated in memory stream, for downloading to user

Tags: asp.net, webforms, openxml

I've got a problem while resolving one task. The task was: Create an opportunity for users to download a .docx document with pasted data. But I'm stuck at the moment at sending the file as a byte array (taken from a `MemoryStream`) to the context's response. Here's a sample:

```cs
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(FileBytes))
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;

        foreach (SdtElement obj in mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().ToList())
        {
            foreach (Text t in obj.Descendants<Text>().ToList())
            {
                switch (t.Text)
                {
                    //.... here is code that fiiling content control's
                }
            }
        }
        myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
        myDoc.Close();
    }

    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
    context.Response.ClearContent();

    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + DocName + ".docx\"");
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
}

context.Response.Flush();
```

The HTTP handler doesn't return any errors - page refresh and download don't start. The handler is calling from JS. Here is the sample of the JS function:

```js
function save_word_doc(id_btn) {
// ... here is code that gets params from default page data

jQuery.post("DataHandler.ashx?CN=" + vCN + "&CommandName=SaveWord&auctionID=" + oFormRecord.auctionID
    + "&user_login=" + user_login
    + ....
    + "&amount=" + oFormRecord.value.amount
    + "&percent=" + percent);
}
```

By the way, this sample code is working well in an ASP.Net MVC project, where the handler is calling from a link button. But this must work in a Web Forms project.

---

Update to pretend questions and incorrect answers: **the file is generated and saved correctly to the local machine.**

Comment: Does `stream` actually contain data when you go to write it out to the Response?

Comment: seems like you'd need to handle this in a callback because you are returning this object to your .post call.  Maybe see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Comment: @mxmissile yeap. Stream got byte viev of my file.

Comment: @pcalkins if it won't make you dificult, sir, provide please some examples. I refered the link and be honest don't understand much )

Comment: basically you can't start a download using javascript...  you can sort of simulate it using an iframe to return the correct headers...  I usually just return a File from the controller. (Task<IActionResult> is the return type.)  "return File(memory, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", sFileName);" If you need javascript for a progress bar or something like that, I believe the post I linked to covers it...

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues in your code. Firstly, `new MemoryStream(FileBytes)` creates a non-resizable `MemoryStream`, which is not what you want in case you are changing the `WordprocessingDocument`. You would should use `new MemoryStream()` to create a resizable `MemoryStream` and copy your `FileBytes` to that `MemoryStream`.

Secondly, since you are in a `using` statement, you don't need the following two lines of code. This is done automatically for you.

```cs
        myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
        myDoc.Close();
```

Lastly, I am not sure about your `ContentEncoding` value for the binary data you are sending. You might want to use a tool like Fiddler or Postman to verify what happens.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The sample code done well if i'm saving the generated file to my local (server etc) storage. The problem is that i can not get any response (file doesn't download in browser). So code work but only for local saving.

Comment: @CaptainHemp, your code with the non-resizable `MemoryStream` might have worked by accident. Look at my [MemoryStreamTests](https://github.com/ThomasBarnekow/CodeSnippets/blob/master/CodeSnippets.Windows.Tests/IO/MemoryStreamTests.cs), which shows that you can't increase the size of your document if the `MemoryStream` is not resizable. For the ASP.NET-related part of your problem, you need to provide more context for us to help you.

Comment: by accident the code could work once, but it’s not so. About more context about ASP.NET-related part: what information is needed?

Comment: We would need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I guess we don't understand each other. The code on question is a example with deleted part, that change content control's (as you can see in sample code as comment), declaration and initialization of variables.

Comment: Code work well, thank you a lot about explanation of `MemoryStream` resizable options. Code work in 2 ways. Firstly - with a `LinkButton` in MVC project that call to "HttpHandler.ashx" which the code that I wrote in question. Works fine. Secondly - in my current project but with option to saving file into "server" local storage that provide this part of code: `File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\new\\"+DocName+".docx", stream.ToArray());`. So problem that i can't get an response on the line `context.Reponse.Flush();`. May be I'm wrong with my JS function, especially with POST request.

Comment: @CaptainHemp, as I said, without a minimal, reproducible example that we can run ourselves, it is nearly impossible to help you.